# Jquery DataTable : Table headers Appearing Twice

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery DataTable for Displaying the data.

```
<style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
    @import '../css/demo_page.css';
    @import '../css/demo_table.css';
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example1').dataTable({
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "bPaginate": false
        });
    });
</script>                                                   

<div id="demo">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example1" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Query GeneID</th>
                <th>Hit GeneID</th>
                <th>EXON</th>
                <th>Percentage</th>
                <th>Align Length</th>
                <th>No. of Mismatch</th>
                <th>Gaps</th>
                <th>Start Query Gene</th>
                <th>End Query Gene</th>
                <th>Hit Gene Start </th>
                <th>End Gene Start</th>
                <th>E-Value</th>
                <th>Bit-Score</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> AA1</td>
                <td>AA3</td>
                <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                <td>AA3</td>
                <td> AA1</td>
                <td> AA1</td>
                <td> AA1</td>
                <td> AA1</td>
                <td> AA1</td>
                <td> AA1</td>
                <td>AA1</td>
                <td>AA1</td>
                <td>AA1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

When I try to hit the page , data is getting shown with all fields in `<th>` appearing twice. 
if I remove:

```
"bAutoWidth": false,
"sScrollX": "100%",
"bPaginate": false
```

Then headers are displaying correctly, I want to keep the scroll enable to make the data scroll able.

Can you please tell where I am making  mistake.

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: I am getting a java Script error :                                  Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'outerWidth'       on file  : jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: I don't see a problem when I try to reproduce: http://live.datatables.net/adayaz/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Thank you  Greg for the link , I found out that I was missing to include the                                                      `<script class="jsbin" src="../scripts/jquery.dataTables.nightly.js"></script>`   After including this code , it started working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery DataTables two rows in head: first row column names and sorting, second row filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752529/jquery-datatables-two-rows-in-head-first-row-column-names-and-sorting-second-r)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation in MVC where headers and footers were both duplicating each time the table was updated from a popup.

The problem turned out to be the duplication of a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

The above script was in both the page and the popup. When I removed it from the popup the headers and footers stopped duplicating.

Comment: This occurred for me when following this [documentation](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html) it indicates DT uses both https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js &
https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.9/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js which duplicates a header at the below the table

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

This worked for me:

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
    $('.dataTables_scrollBody thead tr').css({visibility:'collapse'});
}
```

or in CSS:

```
div.dataTables_scrollBody thead {           
    display: none;
}
```